# Android L notification priority

Tags: android, notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I am developing an app that should change lights of notification LED when other notification is showed. Everything works on android versions below L but on L I am not able to make my notification blink, instead the original notification still blinks even when my notification's priority is MAX and the other's is just HIGH.

Can you please help me a bit with it? Thanks

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setContentTitle(String.format("%s found.", rule.getPattern()));
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_small);
builder.setLights(rule.getColor(), 200, 100);
builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.L) {
    builder.setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE);
}
if (preferences.vibration().get()) {
    builder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 500, 500, 200, 500});
}
notificationManager.notify((int) (long) rule.getId(), builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you described was a bug in **Android 5.0** and is now fixed in **Android 5.1**. Your code seems correct to me and should work as expected on **5.1**.